# adding another dimension/variable to a ggplot2 dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This should be easy but it is driving me crazy.

I have some data of form:

Categories, RetailCPC, AdvertiserCPC
flowers, 0.2, 0.25
shoes, 0.4, 0.1

I am trying to show a dotplot with 2 dots per row and ordered by RetailCPC using ggplot2.

I am able to graph one dimension (by that I mean the RetailCPC data) like so:

```
Mydf$Categories <- reorder(Mydf$Categories, Mydf$RetailCPC)
require(ggplot2) 
p1 <- qplot(RetailCPC, Categories, data = Mydf)
p1 + geom_point(colour = "red", size = 2)
```

How can I add the AdvertiserCPC dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you mean like this:

```
ggplot(melt(Mydf), aes(value, Categories, colour=variable)) + geom_point()
```

note that ggplot has high affinity with "long" format than "wide" format, and `melt` helps to convert from "wide" to "long" format.